# elasticsearch updateByQuery is not updating but returns 200

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch js client and I want to find all fields wirh attrs.tags == XXX and delete the value. The update return 200 and 1 event updated that is correct. But when I list all events I still can see attrs.tags with old value. Why is it not working? Even if I wait for 5 min to give elastic time to update it, I get still the same result.

```
 async function search() {
        var tag = req.body.tags;
        var client = connectToES(res);
        const response = await client.updateByQuery({
            index: "*",
            type: '_doc',
            body: {
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "attrs.tags": tag
                    }
                },
                "script": { "inline": "ctx._source.attrs.tag = ''" }
            }
        });

        client.close();
    }
```

And here is elastic response:

`{"took":34,"timed_out":false,"total":1,"updated":1,"deleted":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}`

Comment: The problem was taht the field tags was array not a string. Update for some reasons didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your ES response seems OK and its exactly mentioning that total 1 document matched its criteria and that document is updated as well, can you cross-check your script and query and see if its matching all your expected documents if not, than you need to construct it properly to update all the documents matching your criteria.